# Retrieve contact details from addressbook in iphone

Tags: iphone

How to retrieve street, city, state and country of a contact from addressbook in iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

NSArray *array= (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

            ABRecordRef person=(ABRecordRef)[array objectAtIndex:i];
    firstName=(NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    lastName=(NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
    streeName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonAddressStreetKey);
    ciy = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonAddressCityKey);
```

Dont forget to add AddressBook and AddressBookUI framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ABAddressBook framework for this.
Have a look @ http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABAddressBook_Class/Reference/Reference.html

[AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html)